# BITMAP Image won't load from file "INVALID HANDLE"

Tags: winapi, bitmap

This is basic, so only one snippet of code from the drawing function is needed because it has the info necessary about the

```
void draw()
{

RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    HBITMAP FRAME1ANIMDASH = NULL;
            FRAME1ANIMDASH = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "Hidden but correct pathname that won't be shown here", 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
            if(FRAME1ANIMDASH == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, "CANNOT LOAD", "CANNOT LOAD", MB_OK);
            }
            HDC device;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH,sizeof(BITMAP),&bm);
    HDC hdcdevice=CreateCompatibleDC(device);
    SelectObject(hdcdevice,FRAME1ANIMDASH);
    BitBlt(device,0,0,0,0,hdcdevice,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    device=GetDC(hwnd);
    DeleteDC(hdcdevice);
    DeleteObject((HBITMAP) FRAME1ANIMDASH);
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        cout << GetLastError();
    }
```

Get last error shows error 6, which is an invalid file handle. The message box shows up, which means the image never loaded and failed, **so the code after it is not the primary concern yet.**

I am trying to load a bitmap and put it on the Win32 window I have created.

No other code is needed, as there's nothing specific about any other code that would lead to a possible answer overall. Tell me what I can do to make the image load successfully.

Comment: Assuming the path is correct and the running process has read access to the resource, I would try replacing `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` by `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE`.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `GetLastError()` too late.  The error code is meaningless at that point as it could be overwritten by any of the other functions you are calling.  You must call `GetLastError()` **immediately** after `LoadImage()` fails:

```
HBITMAP FRAME1ANIMDASH = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(...);
if (FRAME1ANIMDASH == NULL)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    cout << "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE, ERROR " << lastError;
    MessageBox(NULL, "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE", "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE", MB_OK);
    return; // <-- add this, too!
}
```

And the reason why `LoadImage()` is failing is because you are not specifying the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag, and not requesting the image size correctly, per the [`LoadImage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx):

> lpszName [in]
>   ...
>   **If the hinst parameter is NULL and the fuLoad parameter omits the LR_LOADFROMFILE value, the lpszName specifies the OEM image to load.** The OEM image identifiers are defined in Winuser.h and have the following prefixes.
>   ...
>   **If the fuLoad parameter includes the LR_LOADFROMFILE value, lpszName is the name of the file** that contains the stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file). Therefore, set hinst to NULL.
>
> ...
>
> cxDesired [in]
>   ...
>   ... **If this parameter is zero and LR_DEFAULTSIZE is not used, the function uses the actual resource width.**
>
> ...
>
> cyDesired [in]
>   ...
>   ... **If this parameter is zero and LR_DEFAULTSIZE is not used, the function uses the actual resource height.**
>
> ...
>
> fuLoad [in]
>   ...
>   LR_DEFAULTSIZE
>   ... **If this flag is not specified and cxDesired and cyDesired are set to zero, the function uses the actual resource size.**
>   ... 
>   LR_LOADFROMFILE
>   ... Loads the stand-alone image from the **file specified by lpszName** (icon, cursor, or bitmap file).

So it should look more like this:

```
HBITMAP FRAME1ANIMDASH = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "pathname", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Once you fix that, there are other problems with the code.

You are calling `CreateCompatibleDC()` with an **uninitialized** `HDC` variable, and not checking the result of `CreateCompatibleDC()` for failure.  Your call to `GetDC()` is in the wrong place, it needs to be moved above `CreateCompatibleDC()`.  And you are leaking the `HDC` that `GetDC()` returns, you need to call `ReleaseDC()` to free it.

You are also telling `BitBlt()` to copy a 0x0 rectangle of pixels, instead of using the true dimensions of the bitmap from the `BITMAP` structure, or even the window `RECT` that you are retrieving from `GetClientRect()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void draw()
{
    HBITMAP FRAME1ANIMDASH = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "pathname", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if (FRAME1ANIMDASH == NULL)
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        cout << "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE, ERROR " << lastError;
        MessageBox(NULL, "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE", "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    HDC hdcWnd = GetDC(hwnd);
    if (hdcWnd === NULL)
    {
        DeleteObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH);
        cout << "CANNOT GET WINDOW DC";
        MessageBox(NULL, "CANNOT GET WINDOW DC", "CANNOT GET DC", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWnd);
    if (hdcMem == NULL)
    {
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcWnd);
        DeleteObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH);
        cout << "CANNOT CREATE COMPATIBLE DC";
        MessageBox(NULL, "CANNOT CREATE COMPATIBLE DC", "CANNOT CREATE DC", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

    HBITMAP oldBm = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, FRAME1ANIMDASH);
    BitBlt(hdcWnd, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBm);

    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcWnd);
    DeleteObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH);

    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
```

That being said, the `PAINTSTRUCT` variable implies that your code is being used inside of a `WM_PAINT` message handler.  If that is true, you should be using `BeginPaint()` instead of `GetDC()` to get the target `HDC` to draw on:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    draw(hdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
};
```

```
void draw(HDC hdcTarget)
{
    HBITMAP FRAME1ANIMDASH = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "pathname", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if (FRAME1ANIMDASH == NULL)
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        cout << "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE, ERROR " << lastError;
        // DO NOT use MessageBox() in a WM_PAINT handler,
        // You will trigger an endless re-paint loop!
        return;
    }

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcTarget);
    if (hdcMem == NULL)
    {
        DeleteObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH);
        cout << "CANNOT CREATE COMPATIBLE DC";
        return;
    }

    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

    HBITMAP oldBm = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, FRAME1ANIMDASH);
    BitBlt(hdcWnd, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBm);

    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(FRAME1ANIMDASH);
}
```

Otherwise, if you are using your code outside of `WM_PAINT`, then the code is pretty much useless because `UpdateWindow()` will trigger a re-paint that erases your drawing.  Persistent drawings on a window must be done using `WM_PAINT` (unless you are using `UpdateLayeredWindow()` with a `WS_EX_LAYERED` window).

Comment: In your code, it is also too late, since `cout` is built on top of OS file APIs and may also reset the thread last-error value (somewhat unpredictably, depending on how full the buffer is).  The correct approach is `DWORD error_code = GetLastError(); cout << "CANNOT LOAD IMAGE, ERROR " << error_code;`

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is unlikely since `std::cout` is buffered and does not call any APIs during buffering (unless you are thinking of a memory allocation API).  But whatever, I have corrected it.

Comment: In some ways, the buffering makes it even worse -- a Heisenbug even, because adding and removing other code that writes to `cout` would change how full the buffer is at this point, and therefore whether a flush occurs.

Comment: "But whatever" implies contempt to @Ben, who makes a helpful and accurate point. I don't understand why you wrote that rather than "thank you". I also don't understand why you would want to make any assumptions on the implementation of `cout`.

Comment: @David: Well, to be fair he was probably responding to my comment before I edited it to mention buffering and the potential that usage of `cout` could clear last-error codes only part of the time.

Comment: The code doesn't work anyways -- it still says it cannot create the image. Tried all the suggestions mentioned in this answer and I'm still getting the same error message. Directory and image is fine; a 24-bit BITMAP.

Comment: @MargaretRosa: What error code is `GetLastError()` reporting *immediately* after `LoadImage()` fails? You should not be getting error 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`) from `LoadImage()` when loading a file, as there is no handle being operated on. So what error code are you actually getting?

Comment: Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.  So clearly your file path is not as valid as you think it is.

Comment: It was valid ... I finally got it to load the image by moving the BITMAP file to the same folder as the project is in, but it won't load it from anywhere outside of it. I still stand corrected, but I'd like to know how to load from anywhere the same way as possible from the project directory.

Comment: You must be using a **relative path** to the file, so the load would be subject to the process's **current working directory**, which can change dynamically for various reasons during the process's lifetime. When loading a file using a **relative path**, the folder of the process's executable file is always checked first. If the file is not found there, the CWD is checked (amongst other things). To avoid this problem, ALWAYS use an **absolute path** to a file instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using the absolute path to load the image, and it still won't work; it only loads the file in the CWD with just the filename. If I try the absolute, full path with the file outside of the CWD, it won't load the image. Based on the question info alone, it should be obvious that I used an absolute path.

Comment: No, it is not obvious, because you hid the detail of your path and filename. An **absolute path** is not affected by the CWD. If the load fails with error 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`) or 3 (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`) using an **absolute path**, then you are not using a valid path, plain and simple. If you think I'm wrong, feel free to show the actual path you are using, stop hiding it.